# Which topology is best to design a DC DC 120W Power Supply? Kindly go through details

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, design, charger

My requirement is as follows:

1. Input Supply 110+-30% VDC i.e., **77VDC to 138VDC**.
2. output need to be **24VDC 5A**.
3. All the basic protections like **short circuit, Reverse polarity**.
4. **No power** consumption when **no load**.
5. Rugged design to sustain harsh climatic condition.

I have thought to use **Half Bridge LLC topology**. using infenion IC **IRS27952**.

Suggest me better **high Efficiency** topology or another equivalent Transistor drive IC that can surve my purpose.

Comment: I couldn't find any LLC controllers with the name IRFB27952 (Actually I found nothing). Could you please link the datasheet to the actual part?

Comment: Sorry My mistake ..... It was IRS27952.                              https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irs27951s.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567b77792849

Comment: "*No power consumption when no load.*" Not possible. There will have to be some quiescent power.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480002/how-to-select-dc-dc-converter-topology/480044#480044) may help to select topology based on power levels.

> 3. All the basic protections like short circuit, Reverse polarity.

Protection against input voltage with reverse polarity is independent of the converter's topology. You can build a simple reverse polarity protection with a MOSFET (ideally, PMOS) and a few passive components. However, if you want something like "protection against applying voltage from output-side with even reverse polarity" <sup>don't laugh, you can see such requirements in automotive</sup> then things may change.

> 4. No power consumption when no load.

There's no such thing as "no power consumption at no-load". There should be some acceptable power levels. For example, [EU 2019/1782](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32019R1782&from=EN) ANNEX II defines the maximum allowed power consumptions for different power output levels (including no-load). So you should explicitly specify the no-load power consumption.

Anyway, here are my thoughts:

- LLC converters are a bit problematic at no-load regulation. So I'd not go for LLC. But if the controller has some magic inside for no-load regulation then LLC may be an option.
- Flyback could be another option. But flybacks are terrible in terms of EMC performance. Though you didn't specify any EMC requirements so I don't want to say anything extra about this.
- I'd go for either two-switch or active clamp forward converter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 1. I need the short circuit and reverse polarity protection for load only. well i will manage that. battery chargers are the examples where there comes power supply from external sources. 2. No to low power consumption is required. 3. Power supply shall be EMI/EMC compliance.       4. Also can you brief Two switch / active clamp forward convertor.

Comment: `2. No to low power consumption is required.` This is meaningless. Use numbers. 100mW? 10mW? 50mW? You should specify the **exact value**. This is important because this will tell you if you can use a standby regulator for control and, for example, active cooling devices (if necessary). `Also can you brief Two switch / active clamp forward convertor.` There are tons of online documentation. For specific controller ICs there are even reference designs.

Comment: @MdAdil, "*I need the short circuit and reverse polarity protection for load only.*" A power supply can't give reverse polarity protection for the load. Only the load can do that. The best the PSU can do is limit the current.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks for the help. I will be using (Low Side) Active Clamp Forward Convertor. I will use a combination of LT3752 + LT8311. The LT3752 is current mode PWM controllers optimized for an active clamp forward converter topology.  The LT8311 is used on the secondary side of a forward converter to provide synchronous MOSFET control and output voltage feedback through an opto-coupler.

Comment: @Transistor, I got it.

Comment: If my answer is satisfactory and helpful enough then you can accept it so that the question does not remain open.